# Filtering the list with big data - VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I use the filterBy filter from https://github.com/freearhey/vue2-filters. 
The list has about 5,000 records. When I press one letter for example 'a' filtering takes about 10 seconds. When I enter a longer phrase, it takes about a second. Is there any way to speed up the filtering for a single letter of such a large list?

Comment: I don't think you will increase this performance without some pagination. Do you need this 5000 records fetched at once?

Comment: as evaldo said try reduce number of records, pagination is good solution. If you fetch list from database you can filter it on server.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue lies beyond list filtering, and as [Evaldo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4759330/evaldo-bratti) pointed out, Vue simply struggles with rendering a huge amount of components.

Also consider replacing `filterBy` with your own filter implementation. `filterBy` takes a multitude of things into account, including the list type and additional parameters. You need a bare minimum.
The quick way to make an array filter would be

```
 filters: {
    filterBy: (list, searchTerm) => {
      if (!searchTerm) return list;
      return list.filter(x => x.find(searchTerm) !== -1);
    },
  },
```